# Newly framed bathroom wall not square, how bad will the tile look?

Tags: drywall, flooring, tile, framing

I'm in the middle of a new bathroom install and have hit a bit of a snag with a bathroom wall being out of square. This bathroom was just framed from scratch, and as you can see from the attached photo one corner is pretty badly out of square. I already had to have the contractor fix the studs once (before the drywall went up) as they were even further out of whack - the stud in the bad corner was about 2 inches further out that it was supposed to be. But obviously it's still not even close to being square.

This happens to be the side of the bathroom where a tiled shower will be, and since we're using 2"x2" floor tiles, I'm concerned about how this is going to look with that much of a running/angled gap on that side. The last thing I want are little angled tile pieces running along that side. Would you have the contractor redo that section of drywall to make sure it's square? Or would you consider this within acceptable tolerances?

Thanks[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZGKy.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

That looks like nearly 3/4 inch in a 2 foot run. That is a lot of angle, and I think most carpenters would consider it unacceptable on a new framing job (unless there were some underlying issue, like a pipe or an old beam preventing a square outcome).

But it also sounds like your contractor is challenged when it comes to getting something square. You can try again, but you may still be disappointed.

An alternative is to use a [brick pattern](http://www.ninostile.com/index_TilePatterns.htm) on the floor.

[image: brick tile]

The lack of a straight line on the left would make the angle cuts less noticeable.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to have him redo that then.  Thanks for your input bib!

Answer (score 0):

When tasked with the a similar problem, I chose to square the wall up with the existing framing. My wall was out of plum, and out of square - I shimmed it floor to ceiling, corner to corner.

[image: shims 1]
[image: shims 2]
[image: shims 3]